# Setting up VST Steinberg SDK on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, codeblocks, vst

I need to write a basic VST plugin (2.4) in Visual C++. I Googled it, but what I found is lots of deprecated descriptions with dead links. Could anyone recommend me a good step by step guide which helps setting up the environment in Windows 7 (I would like to use Code Blocks) and test the plugin with the test host?

[This](http://learnvst.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/build-vst-plugins-using-codeblocks/) blogpost says that it's possible to build the plugin in Code Blocks. I followed the instructions, but in the [latest Steinberg SDK](http://www.steinberg.net/en/company/developers.html) the files are different.

Answer (score 0):

VST2.4 and VST3.x versions of the SDK are different things. If you want to build a 2.4 VST Plugin you may need to find yourself a copy of the 2.4 SDK. Officially the 2.4 SDK has been deprecated and Steinberg may have stopped distributing it. To make things difficult, Steinberg's licensing prevents third parties from distributing it as well.

No doubt any tutorials for 2.x VST Plugin development will be out of date regarding the latest 3.x SDK and vice-versa.

The VST 3.x SDK contains a 2.x wrapper so newer format plugins can be wrapped and distributed as 2.4 plugins. I can't comment on how well that works in practice as I haven't tried it.