# C++ ASIO driver setup

Tags: c++, audio, steinberg-asio

I ask you for help with the setup of ASIO sdk. I would like to use it to connect some external devices to my system but before that I am struggling to even join ASIO to my programme.

I've downloaded ASIO 2.3 from there:
http://www.steinberg.net/en/company/developers.html

and unfortunately C++ isn't my strongest point. SDK contains few folders (is folder named "Common" having every file needed?), there is no *.lib file only *.cpp and *.h files.

1. I don't know which files are necessary so the SDK is installed completely.
2. I was thinking about merging everything into one library but I don't know which files are important for SDK...
3. Can you give me any hints how can I add files to my program so I can start using ASIO functions in my code?

Comment: You're effectively asking the generic question, "how do I incorporate a third party library into my project?", which is incredibly broad. Maybe some kind soul will come forth and write the 5-8 paragraphs necessary, but I suspect this is way too broad for SO.

Comment: Haha. Finally found when I tinkered with this: _[@Ell haha. Only 20 minutes of bloody tinkering at their site to... download the freaking SDK. Gotta love priorities - sehe Jan 28 2014](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14352770#14352770)_. I remember I got it to work (Linux) but don't recall any specific tricky points.

Comment: I can probably answer the question for you but first you need to tell me your operating system and development environment.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly I haven't documented my ordeal last year. However, here's some pointers:

- [How to begin building a VSTi Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477868/how-to-begin-building-a-vsti-plugin/26561096#26561096)
- [Setting up VST Steinberg SDK on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737625/setting-up-vst-steinberg-sdk-on-windows/24773393#24773393)
- [Build a minimal VST3 host in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478173/build-a-minimal-vst3-host-in-c/24485576#24485576)

I admit that's basically cherry-picking the list of SO results for "steinberg", but at least the first 2 seem relevant.

Comment: The question is about ASIO, not VST plugins.

Comment: @jaket Good point. I think the first covers both though. Both libraries are part of the Steinberg SDK